# C++ chrono Time Conversation Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I've a problem with saving a timestamp -

In the header file I have the following code:

```
long *_lastHeartbeat;
```

And now I want save the time in _lastHeartbeat:

```
_lastHeartbeat = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1);
```

But I get only this error -

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘std::__success_type<long int>::type {aka long int}’ to ‘long int*’ [-fpermissive]
lastHeartbeat = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1);
                                                                    ^
```

And I don't know what to do.

EDIT:
The main problem is solved but I've another question: I saved it like this: _lastHeartbeat = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1); 
But then the thread stopped after: 
https://github.com/THOMAS-Projekt/THOMAS/blob/master/MotorControl.cpp#L222 This happened also if I save other data.

If I commet it out, it worked

Comment: You cannot assign a `long` to a *pointer* to `long`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not save a std::chrono::time_point?

Comment: How should I do this otherwise? Without a pointer?

Comment: @Waishon: You probably just want to declare the variable not to be a pointer, `long lastHeartbeat;` If it is meant to be a pointer for some reason, you'll have to explain why, and what it points to.

Comment: @TNA I want to save the milliseconds. Does it works with time_point?

Comment: `auto timepoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now()`?

Comment: Why are you using a pointer? You haven't explained that.

Comment: @Waishon "How should I do this otherwise? Without a pointer?" - if you're asking that, you seriously need to reread the chapter on pointers in whatever book you've been reading about C++, with particular attention to the word "dereference".

Comment: Everybody is learning at one time. I know what are pointers. My english is not the best, so if I read something like this: 
"You cannot assign a long to a pointer to long" than I doesn't know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save milliseconds:

```
auto timestamp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto time_since_epoche = timestamp.time_since_epoch();
auto milliseconds_since_epoch = std::chrono::timepoint_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time_since_epoche);
std::cout "milliseconds since epoche: " << miliseconds_since_epoche.count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unsigned long instead of long pointer.

```
unsigned long lastHeartBeat =
    std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() / 
    std::chrono::milliseconds(1);
```

I hope this would work fine in your case.